# lead to vs relocate

Tags: phrase-meaning, passive-voice, complements

I read "lead many companies to relocate in rural areas (1)"

This is typo ?

We can make a complete sentence " The government leads many companies to relocate in rural areas "

I have a doubt that " The government leads many companies to be relocate in rural areas " is correct sentence.

My reason is as follows : lead to = bring, relocate=arrange.

Hence (1) is correct ?

Comment: It might help to read *lead to* in the broad sense of *persuade*. The government ‘persuaded’ them relocate. Whether it is a typo, I don’t know - you’ll need to compare the quote in context with the intended message. It needn’t be one, though.

Comment: You mean "They relocate". Because they are companies, then we need a passive voice ?

Comment: No, I don’t mean “They relocate”.

Comment: I can not understand the sentence grammartically The government persuaded them relocate ?  If you mean the government persuaded them relocated, then I can understand.

Comment: Typo on my part: persuaded them *to* relocate. Apologies. I had *made* instead of *persuaded* initially, but thought it was too strong a synonym for *lead*.

Comment: I do not understand the part "to relocate".  to be relocated is right ?

Comment: To *relocate* means to move their operations to a different address. It doesn’t have to be expressed in the passive voice.

Comment: They=companies. So they are relocated in rural areas. I think that this is right form.

Comment: Companies can *relocate*. They don’t have to “be relocated”.